# Help with Mean Value Theorem Question

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f:\mathbb{R} \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function on $[0,3]$ and differentiable on $(0,3)$. With $f(0)=1$ and $f(1)=f(3)=2$.

Show that $\exists c \in (0,3)$ with $f'(c) = \frac{1}{4}$

PS: I know that exists $c \in (0,3)$ with $f'(c)=\frac{1}{3}$, by the Mean Value Theorem.

Comment: Yes, that's it. Sorry.

Comment: You have three values $0,1,3$ so you have three pairs on which to use the mean for value theorem.  There is a $c \in (0,3)$ where $f'(c)=\frac 13$.  There is a $d \in (1,2)$ where $f'(d) = 0$ and an $e\in (0,1)$ where $f'(e) = 1$.  Now use intermediate value theorem on $f'$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you correctly stated, by the [mean value theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem), there is an $a \in (0,3)$ such that $f'(a) = \frac{f(3) - f(0)}{3 - 0} = \frac{1}{3}$. Using the mean value theorem again, there's a $b \in (1,3)$ such that $f'(b) = \frac{f(3) - f(1)}{3 - 1} = 0$. Finally, by [Darboux's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darboux%27s_theorem_(analysis)) which says the derivative has the intermediate value property, since $0 \lt \frac{1}{4} \lt \frac{1}{3}$, there's a $c$ in $(\min(a,b),\max(a,b))$, with this set obviously also being in $(0,3)$, where $f'(c) = \frac{1}{4}$.

Update: Changed the text above to no longer state need to assume derivative is continuous since Darboux's theorem shows it's not required for the intermediate value property to apply.

Comment: Derivatives possess intermediate value property without the necessity of being continuous.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Thanks for pointing this out.  It's been too many years since I last studied & used calculus (about $30$ years) that I forgot about Darboux's theorem.  As such, I've updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: +1 there for the update.

Answer (score 3):

There is no need to assume the derivative is continuous. By Darboux's theorem, derivatives always satisfy the intermediate value property (prove this! It's not so bad).

Then, argue that there is a point $c\in (0,1)$ where the derivative is $1$, and a point $c'\in (1,3)$ where $f'(c')=0$, and so there must be a $c''$ between these two points where $f'(c'')$ takes on any value between $0$ and $1$ you wish.